# Difference between code and verbatim in Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

What is the intended difference between `~code~` and `=verbatim=` markup in Org-mode? Exporting to HTML in both cases yields `<code>` tags.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Org 8.0 (ox-* exporters) there are a few differences.

#### In LaTeX

- Code comes out as `\verb{sep}content{sep} where {sep} is found as an appropriate delimiter.
- Verbatim comes out as \texttt{content} with certain characters escaped/protected.

#### In HTML and ODT

Code and Verbatim are treated identically

#### In TeXInfo

The same behaviour is followed as in LaTeX.

Comment: If you want to make code and verbatim different in html output, you can modify `org-html-text-markup-alist`.

Answer (score 17):

Same for LaTeX...

Though, as they are fontified differently in your buffer, you can use them for different semantics.

Personally, I use "code" for var/func names, commands to be typed, etc; and "verbatim" for paths or file names.

I would have loved to have the same number of markups as there are in TeX Info, but that's not the case...